# how to display date like below image?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to format a Date String in React Native.
ex: 2nd NOV.
My problem is I have to show as it mention in the image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKNGs.png)

Comment: Can you share code you have already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use MomentJS https://momentjs.com/ - it is a nice easy Library that lets you manipulate Dates and also Format it the way you want it. Check the "Display" Section in the Docs and there the "format" Function.

I guess in your case it would look something like this:

```
Moment(yourDate).format("DO MMM");
```

Answer (score -2):

A js alternative :

```
new Date().toLocaleDateString('en', { day: 'numeric', month: 'short' })
```

it would display the day and month according to the locale you choose